# Redirect website if the content is difference

Tags: javascript, redirect

I created a code to redirect a website in case the content of the link is different, it redirects to my website. But, the website is being redirect even if the content is exactly equal. What's wrong with my javascript code?

Ps.: Yes, I know the client may delete the code, and etc. I just want to know what's wrong with code.

```
<div id="credits">
   <span class='credits'>Design <a href='https://portfolio.com' target='_blank'>Designer</a></span>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('span.credits > a') != 'https://portfolio.com') {
         window.location = 'https://portfolio.com'
      } else {
         return False;
      }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be comparing the element's `href` attribute, not the element itself:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('span.credits > a').attr('href') != 'https://portfolio.com') {
    window.location = 'https://portfolio.com'
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="credits">
  <span class='credits'>Design <a href='https://portfolio.com' target='_blank'>Designer</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you (Unfortunately I cannot vote, but thanks).